# What's the best approach to testing private Stateless components functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say we have this stateless component

```
import React from ‘react’;

const HelloWorld = ({name}) => (

  const sayHi = event => {
    alert(`Hi ${name}`);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <a 
        href="#"
        onClick={sayHi}>Say Hi</a>
    </div>
  );
);

export default HelloWorld;
```

What's the best approach to testing `sayHi` function?
Knowing that I to do unit testing for it.

Comment: A stateless function is still a function. You want to make sure it does what it says on the tin, it doesn't do something funny with unsanitary input, that it actually executes something on the virtual DOM, etc. Making it stateless doesn't change the nature of the testing you have to do. Perhaps I don't understand your question.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Is not actually about the stateless function at all.
My question is, given the above example what's the best approach to testing `sayHi` function since I can't access it from outside (any test  framework).

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty straightforward if you just look at the [Jest docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#content). You basically want to simulate a click and mock/spy the `alert` call.

Roughly something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';

test('that alert is called when clicking link', () => {

  const testName = 'Jack';
  // Render a checkbox with label in the document
  const hw = shallow(
    <HelloWorld name={testName} />
  );

  const alert = jest.fn();

  hw.find('a').simulate('click');
  expect(alert).toBeCalledWith('Hi ' + testName);
});
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but What I want to avoid is to access to my private function through HTML events.  
Furthermore isn't this already  E2E test, is a good practice combining unit test and E2E test?

Comment: @JoseAPL I am not sure what to say about your wanting to "avoid access to [your] private function through HTML events". My understanding is the code I've provided is pretty much _the_ way one would test the component you provided. Additionally, it's my understanding that combining unit and E2E test is _not_ good practice, but I don't really see where unit testing is coming into play here.